# 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: django, django-serializer

**My Models  related with foreign key:**

```
class Speaker(models.Model):
    speaker = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Course(models.Model):
    ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(Speaker, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='course_author')
```

**My serializers:**

```
class SpeakerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Speaker
        fields = ['id',...]

class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ....
    author = SpeakerSerializer(many=False, required=True)
    ....
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ['id', 'author',...]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...
        author = validated_data.get('author')
        ...
        course, _ = Course.objects.create(author=author.id, **validated_data)

        course.save()
```

**I'm sending POST request to this serializer and getting this response:**
Help please!

```
course, _ = Course.objects.create(author=author.id, **validated_data)
AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
author_id = validated_data.pop('author').get('id')
```

and make sure you send a correct nested JSON API.

Comment: Hi Mohamed. I did like you said, and got this: 
  `django.db.models.manager.BaseManager._get_queryset_methods.<locals>.create_method.<locals>.manager_method() got multiple values for keyword argument 'author'`

Comment: Hi @AskajonAbdullayev, that's because we send an `author` failed twice within the create method. please add your models to the question to understand your pattern.

Comment: let's try to `pop` the `author` field from `validated_data`, see the updated answer.

Comment: now i'm getting this: `ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Course.author" must be a "Speaker" instance.`

Comment: We need to create a `Speaker` object and pass it to `author` field, that makes sense, but before that, show me how your data in nested JSON API looks like to make sure there is no error again.

Comment: I added this after poping author: `author = Speaker.objects.get(id=author_id)` and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear that! and I suggest you use `serializers.Serializer` instead of using `serializers.ModelSerializer` for performance issues, you can read more about that here: https://hakibenita.com/django-rest-framework-slow
have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 'author.id', please use author['id'] to fetch the value to id in OrderdDic object.